# Rake tasks work locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake-task

I have a rake task that loads data into tables of my database. I made changes recently to my schema, and migrating them to heroku appears to have worked fine. However, when I run my rake task, I get the following error message: 
`Don't know how to build task 'import_foursquare_response:create_records'`

and a less than helpful stack trace:

```
heroku run rake import_foursquare_response:create_records --trace
Your version of git is 2.2.0. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
Running `rake import_foursquare_response:create_records --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.5353
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'import_foursquare_response:create_records'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Most of the questions I've seen have pointed to syntax errors in the way people had written the actual rake task, but I can't see any problems there.

```
require 'four_square'

namespace :import_foursquare_response do
  include FourSquare

  desc "Load database with results of API calls"
  task :create_records => :environment do
    puts "Loading database..."
```

Any help is much appreciated. No data makes my app useless.

Comment: Does the task work locally and can you see it when running rake -T? Does the file that has the definition of the task end in .rake?

Comment: Yes. Everything works locally. I can build my local database using this rake task (it appears along with all the others with `rake -T` and ends in .rake). I was getting "syntax error" messages for a hash in the rake task, but then realized I had pushed the new code to heroku before migrating the new schema. After rolling back, migrating, and pushing, I can't get past the error that shows in the code I posted above, so no logs to help me debug.

Comment: That's odd. I wonder if after the rollback the rake task didn't get pushed up for some reason. You could try a force push or adding and empty commit and pushing (```git commit --allow-empty -m "empty commit"
git push heroku master```) to make sure that your local repo is in sync with Heroku.

Comment: Seems like your suggestion may be on to something. Now when I attempt to run the rake task on heroku, I'm getting a syntax error, which at least means that heroku sees the task. Now I'm getting a syntax error, which I'm stumped on. Any thoughts as to why heroku throws an error on the following when it works just fine locally:
`/app/lib/tasks/fetch_foursquare_data.rake:19: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
/app/lib/tasks/fetch_foursquare_data.rake:20: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
      "Bar":"4bf58dd8d48988d11b941735,4bf...
            ^`

Comment: That looks to me like an issue with the you are loading via the rake task. That's the kind of error I would expect from malformed json or yaml.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Lukas. I'll see if I can troubleshoot this with some of the other S.O. threads I see about yaml issues in heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it is just because heroku does not do any disk writing with rake tasks, please see below:

[image: Heroku Limitations]

Src: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake

Comment: why are you guessing?

Comment: It's possible to run custom rake task, which writes to DB ie: ```heroku run rake membership:create``` Initially I had an error but it was because I had this line on the beginning of my code ```return unless Rails.env.development?```